# Why does 'tick := time.Tick(time.Second)' ticks every 2 seconds instead of 1 second

Tags: go

This is rather simple, but I can't figure it out...

I am trying to make a time.Tick every seconds... but it ticks every 2 seconds?!?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    
    iterationIndex := 0
    tick := time.Tick(time.Second)
    done := make(chan bool, 1)

    for _ = range tick {
        select {
        case <-tick:
            iterationIndex++
            if iterationIndex >= 10{
                done <- true
            }
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", time.Now().Format("15:04:05.000000"))
        case <-done:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

links to go playground
https://play.golang.org/p/WKhnNK2BRpd

Comment: because of the `range`, use just `for` without the `range`.

Comment: @EminLaletovic - can you explain? the example at https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Tick includes `for next := range c`

Comment: Hint: add a `default:` case to your `select`.

Comment: @jakub, yes that example is correct. it uses `range` to get ticks from the channel. But, in the question above, both `range` and `select - case` statements are used to get values from the `tick` channel. That is why only the second tick is always logged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is where the mistake is:

```
for _ = range tick {
        select {
        case <-tick:
```

What happens is that you get one tick through `for _ = range tick`, and another tick through `select { case <-tick:`. And you log the second tick always.

To log every tick you need to do this:

```
for {
        select {
        case <-tick:
            iterationIndex++
            if iterationIndex >= 10{
                done <- true
            }
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", time.Now().Format("15:04:05.000000"))
        case <-done:
            return
        }
    }
```

Here you handle and log each tick.

**EDIT:**

If you really want to use the `for ... range` statement instead, you can do something like this:

```
for _ = range tick{
    if iterationIndex >= 10{
        break
    }
    iterationIndex++
        
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", time.Now().Format("15:04:05.000000"))
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Go is so fun :) really scratched my head with that one... channels are so powerful, yet quite hard to wrap your head around.